# Run python script at specific date

Tags: pi-3, python

I have a Python script that executes every minute on my Raspberry Pi. 
What I want to do now is that this infinite loop that repeats itself every minute, starts at an specific date that I can control, let's say in a month or on July 17th, whatever date I set. I have seen how to get today's date, but not to run something on an specific day and time.

This is the code that I have:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    #HERE IS WHERE I WRITE THE TASK


schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job)


while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

What do you guys suggest?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: This is a programming question. Look into `datetime.timedelta` class.

Answer (score 6):

## Revised Answer:

After re-reading the question (2+ years later!) I've concluded my original answer may not have been the best answer. I've left the original answer (below), and adding this *Edited* answer.

### Edited Answer:

In re-reading the question, it seems to me now that the OP's objective is to execute his code (a Python script) at an **arbitrary** time in the future; i.e. **not** on a repetitive schedule (*á la* `cron`), and **not** on a relative elapsed time from starting a program (*á la* `datetime.timedelta` class). This is not to say that the OP's objectives cannot be met with these methods, but there is a utility that seems perfectly suited to this objective: `at`

The `at` utility **"executes commands at a specified time"**. It is not currently installed by default, so the first step is to install it:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
...
$ sudo apt install at
```

Scheduling with `at` is unconventional, but straightforward. `man at` provides a reasonable guide, and [other useful docs are available](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm). Two things to know before using `at`:

1. all commands will be executed using `/bin/sh`
2. output from commands goes to the user's **mailbox** by default

These need not be restrictive:

1. Python (and other executable code/scripts) may be run from a shell script
2. output may be redirected to a file - but not (easily) to `stdout`/terminal

For example, a Python script may be run using `/bin/sh` in (at least) two ways; consider the following examples:

#### 1. Embedded in a shell script:

Create a script/file named `MyShell.sh` with "embedded" Python:

```
python3 - <<END
print('Hello, world!')
END
```

Schedule it using `at`:

```
$ chmod 755 MyShell.sh 
$ at -f /home/pi/MyShell.sh 13:30
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 9 at Mon Aug 31 13:30:00 2020
```

Anytime after this date & time, see the output in your mail spool:

```
$ mail

# ... , reading from the applicable message:

From: pi@raspberrypi4b.local
Date: Mon, 31 Aug 2020 13:30:00 -0000

Hello, world!
? q
$
```

#### 2. Python script called from a shell script:

Assume the name of the Python script to be executed at some future time is `MyPython.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print('Hello from PythonWorld!')
```

We may create a shell script `MyShell2.sh` to run `MyPython.py`:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/MyPython.py
```

To run `MyShell2.sh` on Oct 21, 2030 at 12:00 noon:

```
$ at -f /home/pi/MyShell2.sh 12:00 PM 10/21/2030  
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 13 at Mon Oct 21 12:00:00 2030
$
```

As a "one-line" shell script, this can also run this as a command in `at` directly, and verified by `atq`:

```
$ at 12:00 PM 10/21/2030
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/MyPython.py
at> <EOT>
job 14 at Mon Oct 21 12:00:00 2030

$ atq
14  Mon Oct 21 12:00:00 2030 a pi
$
```

### Original Answer:

<strike>Use `cron`; it's designed for this. Trying to accomplish your objective in `Python` is like... I don't know, swatting flies with a sledgehammer? But that's strictly your choice of course.</strike>

`cron` is really quite easy to use, and the documentation is on your system:

```
man cron 
man crontab
```

Briefly, you'll edit your crontab as follows:

```
crontab -e
```

and you'll create a "schedule" for executing your Python program. Also, Debian (and therefore Raspbian) support non-standard schedules, including `@reboot` which runs a job/script/whatever when the machine reboots. Lots of online resources available for "hacking" cron:

- https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md
- http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Answer (score 2):

You could try this if you want to incorporate the delay into your code:

```
import datetime
from time import sleep
import schedule

day_to_run = 10 # run this starting on the 10th
month_to_run = 5 # run this in may(the 5th month)

def job():
    #HERE IS WHERE I WRITE THE TASK

while 1:
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    if date.day == day_to_run and date.month == month_to_run:
        break # this breaks out of the while loop if it's the right day.
    else:
        sleep(60) #wait 60 seconds

schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job) #continue with the rest of the program

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    sleep(1)
```

Or you could use cron, as @Fabian says, which would schedule the script to run on a certain day:

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

https://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/

[running cron specific day of the month](https://techblog.covermymeds.com/general/running-cron-first-specific-day-month/)

Hope this helps!